# Discovering a complex PHP error

Tags: php, fork, proc-open

We have an application currently crawling the web on a dedicated CentOS server, using Plesk. The application makes use of `proc_open` and `exec`, and it usually works but eventually fails. The error logs sometimes shows 2 interesting errors: `Unable to fork` followed by a sequence of pipe errors - other times nothing.

Like I mentioned before, the problem is that the application suddenly and randomly stops after crawling for a few hours/days, and usually there's not even proper debugging / profiling information in the PHP error logs.

Is there any application, software, suit, method, or any other kind of solution to monitor the server resources and errors, and get a full idea of what could be happening that makes the application stop?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try NewRelic for monitoring your server and software.

Your forking issue may be a file descriptor limit or PID limit of the machine.

Try increasing the PID max

echo 5000000 > /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but I already tried both my friend, there's no error information at all at this point. NewRelic doesn't provide any information regarding the interruption. As well, I tried to keep track of the memory usage, it doesn't reach any limit... I'm lost here.